# Aggregation with Regular Expressions in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, substring, distinct, aggregation

I am new at Elasticsearch and I want to learn how to write distinct queries for substrings. Like we do in SQL:

```
SELECT distinct substring(abc,3,5)
FROM table_a
```

I have this query, and I want to make distinct selection on `substring(message,35,10)` part of the message:

```
{   
"query" : 
{ "range":{
        "@timestamp" : {
            "gte" : "now-6d/d",
            "lt" :  "now-5d/d"
        }
}},
"_source":["@timestamp","message"],
"size":100,
"from":0
}
```

I think I have to add something like:

```
"aggs": {
    "distinct": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "message",--should have something like substring 
            "size": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"script"` instead of `"field"` inside your *Terms Aggregation*. Here you can perform substring or any common operation with the field value.

Note: Using script inside an aggregation may make the query execution very slow!

[Terms Aggregation - Scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script)